# insert to from multiple to one table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select from  two table column datas and insert it into another table I can this but it copy 6 times.

I tried this code it works but insert 6 time in to table3.

```
insert into table3(LisanNo , UserName, table1ID, 
NameAndLastName , table2Id)
select table1.LisansNo, table1.UserName, table1.Id, 
table2.NameAndLastName,table2.Id
form table1, tabl2;
```

Enter code here-

```
**Table1**
id      LisansNo    UserName
1.     f3ewrwer     aaa
2.     r3we3        bbb

**Table2**

id   NameLastName
3.   john ddd
4.   hhhhh
9.    yyyy
11.  terere
```

I want to insert this Two table to another table.

```
table 3
id  LisanNo   UserName table1ID  NameLastName Table2ID
1.  f3ewrwer   aaa      1         john ddd     3
2.  r3we3      bbb      2          hhhhh       4
3.                                 yyyy        9
4.                                 terere      11
```

Comment: What's the relation between table1 and table2??

Comment: No any relation in here

Comment: So how do you make table3??  Why do you get the f3ewrwer row with the jhon ddd row? How do you pass from 6 rows (2 in table1 and 4 in table2) to 4 rows in table3????

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: table3 already created ,, there is not any passing .. i want to insert datas of table1 and table2 to table 3

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to list the values vertically.  This is not a very SQL'ish thing to do, but you can accomplish it:

```
select t1.LisansNo, t1.UserName, t1.Id, 
       t2.NameAndLastName, t2.Id
from (select t1.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as seqnum
      from table1 cross join
           (select @rn1 := 0) params
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as seqnum
      from tabl2 t2 cross join
           (select @rn2 := 0) params
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks soo much,, but it's just insert up to count of table1 .. and table2  the last 2 rows not inserted